# files with certain extension won't upload in typo3

Tags: upload, typo3

I have a typo3 website, where a user can upload files. I have set no restrictions for files types, however some extensions won't upload and I get a 500 server error message. I could only recognize those types : .exe, .pptx , .potx, .pptm, .xlsm, .xlsx and .xltx.

Could it be that my host restrict those extension for security purposes ? or is it a common issue in Typo3 ?

thanks in advance

Comment: TYPO3 has a pattern of files that cannot be uploaded. The default value for this pattern is this: `\.(php[3-6]?|phpsh|phtml)(\..*)?$|^\.htaccess$`. Not the part `(\..*)?`, it denies any file containing for example `.php.`. However, it is weird that you get a `500`-response, not something else.

Comment: yep, this is the exact error message I get :  Server error response [url] http://server.de/api/media/insert [status code] 500 [reason phrase] Internal Server Error. Otherwise what error should be generated ?

Comment: In addition , those configuration are not to be found in localconf.php. I even added this line of code :  $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['fileExtensions']['webspace']['allow'] = 'exe,pptx,potx,pptm,xlsm,xlsx,xltx';
   but nothing has changed

Comment: Check your error log to see what the actual error is.